Neyman on definition of null hypothesis and equivalence of "accepting H0" and "not rejecting H0"
I've been trying to understand the ways in which there is (and isn't) an asymmetry between the null hypothesis and the alternative hypothesis in Neyman-Pearson hypothesis testing. When reading different sources, I've noticed that Neyman (at least in 1950) and many subsequent authors differ in their presentation. Is this merely a difference in pedagogical/presentation style or is it a difference in substance? If the latter, what is the justification for it?
How Neyman presented it: In his book "First course in probability and statistics" (1950) https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.233506/page/259/mode/2up?view=theater, p. 259, Neyman writes

In consequence, $\bar{H}$ will be described as the negation of $H$ and vice versa. The choice between the two actions $A$ and $B$ is interpreted as the adoption or the acceptance of one of the hypotheses $H$ and the rejection of the other. Thus, if the application of an adopted rule of inductive behavior leads to action $A$, we say that the hypothesis $H$ is accepted (and, therefore, $\bar{H}$ is rejected). On the other hand, if the application of the rule leads to action $B$, we say that the hypothesis $H$ is rejected (and, therefore, the hypothesis $\bar{H}$ is accepted).

On p. 159-160 he continues:

The terms "accepting" and "rejecting" a statistical hypothesis are very convenient and are well established. It is important, however, to keep their exact meaning in mind and to discard various additional implications which may be suggested by intuition. Thus, to accept a hypothesis $H$ means only to decide to take action $A$ rather than action $B$. This does not mean that we necessarily believe that the hypothesis is true. Also, if the application of a rule of inductive behavior "rejects" $H$, this means only that the rule prescribes action $B$ and does not imply that we believe that $H$ is false.

Up to this point, it has for Neyman been immaterial which of the hypotheses is labelled "null hypothesis" (or "hypothesis tested"; footnote on p. 259) and which is labelled "alternative hypothesis". On p. 263--264, Neyman introduces the convention that you label the hypotheses "null" and "alternative" based on the costs of type I and II errors in such a way that type I errors are the more costly ones. Some asymmetry in the treatment creeps in when a suboptimal test statistic is used, due to it being easier and prioritized to control the type I error, but the treatment of the null and alternative hypothesis is largely symmetric.
Examples of other presentations: Most texts either use much vaguer language that is perhaps consistent with what Neyman had in mind, but leaves open other interpretations as well, or make statements that are inconsistent with Neyman's.
As an example, Bhattacharya and Johnson "Statistical concepts and methods" (1977) write on p.~167:

Choice of $H_0$ and $H_1$


When an investigation is aimed at establishing an assertion with the substantive support obtained from the sample, the negation of the assertion is taken to be the null hypothesis $H_0$ and the assertion itself is taken to be the alternative.

and further, on p.~168,

In testing a null hypothesis $H_0$ against an alternative $H_1$, our attitude is to uphold $H_0$ as true unless the data speak strongly against it, in which case, $H_0$ should be rejected in favor of $H_1$. False rejecting $H_0$ is viewed as a more serious error than failing to reject $H_0$ when $H_1$ is true.

Compared to Neyman's presentation, the distinction between taking action $A$ vs. believing $H_0$ as well as taking action $B$ vs. believing $H_1$ is here muddled. Moreover, the surrounding text can perhaps be read as consistent with the null hypothesis being defined as the hypothesis that it is more costly to wrongly reject. However, by not saying so explicitly and by introducing other considerations (like what an investigation is aimed at establishing, or whether a new claim is "valid") the overall impression I get is that it is not only the cost of type I and II errors that define which is "null" and "alternative", respectively.
On p. 174 in the same book is another example:

[...] there is an element of vagueness in the conclusion reached by testing the statistical hypothesis. In particular, the retention of $H_0$ should be interpreted only as lack of evidence to reject it. This does not mean that there is enough evidence to support it. Therefore, rather than saying $H_0$ is accepted, a more appropriate phraseology is to say that $H_0$ is not rejected.

Where Neyman is explicit about "accepting $H_0$" being exactly the same action as "not rejecting $H_0$", these authors suggest that there is an asymmetry between "accepting $H_0$" and "accepting $H_1$" that makes the former better worded as "not rejecting $H_0$". This I think comes from them setting up the problem as one of "establishing an assertion", rather than as the problem of choosing between two actions $A$ and $B$.
Another example is from an online textbook https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/09%3A_Hypothesis_Testing/9.01%3A_Introduction_to_Hypothesis_Testing:

In hypothesis testing, the goal is to see if there is sufficient statistical evidence to reject a presumed null hypothesis in favor of a conjectured alternative hypothesis.


Note the asymmetry between the null and alternative hypotheses. This asymmetry is due to the fact that we assume the null hypothesis, in a sense, and then see if there is sufficient evidence in $x$ to overturn this assumption in favor of the alternative.

Here there is no mention of costs of type I and II errors being what defines the null and alternative hypotheses. Instead, the null is taken to be presumed and the alternative conjectured.
What I've considered: The difference in presentation could be due to authors (i) trying to present Neyman-Pearson's method in a manner that emphasizes what it has in common with Fisher's method, (ii) being resigned to the fact that readers will practice a hybrid of Fisher's and Neyman-Pearson's methods where careful consideration of costs and power is neglected and non-cost-based conventional significance thresholds are used, (iii) being aware of developments after 1950 that generalized Neyman-Pearson's theory and made the simple cost-based definition of "null" and "alternative" inadequate. However, I'm not certain which, if any, of these actually explain the differences in presentation.
I've also read the closely related Does failure to reject the null in Neyman-Pearson approach mean that one should "accept" it?
Either self-contained answers here or any reference to a text that discusses these issues explicitly would be appreciated.

Seems to me that any time a part of the N–P approach is taken out of the context of the whole method it becomes hard to communicate without introducing ambiguities and confusion. To quote from myself, "A Neyman–Pearsonian hypothesis test is more than a simple statistical calculation. It is a method that properly encompasses experimental planning and experimenter behaviour as well." (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286)

I would add to your item (ii) the possibility that the authors themselves are unaware that they are promoting an incomplete or ill-formed variant of the N–P approach.

The discussion of the accept/reject thing is a little simpler in the situation where the null is a point in the parameter space of the statistical model and the alternative is the rest of the range of possible parameter values (i.e. the not the null hypothesis hypothesis). In such a case the accepting the alternative is an identical 'action' to failing to reject the null.
